# Accessing Property of Class in List<Class>

Tags: c#

I see a lot of similar questions but none with a direct answer.  I have a `List<ClientEntry>`.  I want to access properties in ClientEntry.  My code looks like this:

```
class ClientEntry
{
    private string _clientName;
    private string _clientEmail;

    public void ClientEntry(string name, string email)
    {
        this._clientName = name;
        this._clientEmail = email;
    }

    public string ClientName
    {
        get
        {
            return _clientName;

        }
        set
        {
            _clientName = value;
        }
    }

    public string ClientEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return _clientEmail;
        }
        set
        {
            RegexUtilities Validator = new RegexUtilities();
            if (Validator.IsValidEmail(value))
            {
                _clientEmail = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Later:

```
private List<ClientEntry> clientList;
```

I then add a bunch of ClientEntry's to the List.

How can I access the ClientName and ClientEmail properties for items in clientList?  Also, how can I check for the existance of a certain ClientName or ClientEmail property within the List?  Is this even possible with a list of objects?  I know a dict would probably serve better, but I wanted to see if this could be done with a List and a class with properties.

Comment: Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `ClientEntry` and use Contains, IndexOf, Remove,and indexer to access the list items.

Comment: Could you provide a short example of such overrides and I'll accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Linq to look for values inside of a list using `Any()`

Eg.

```
bool emailExists = clientList.Any(x=>x.ClientEmail == <email>);
```

To access values, you can use a index accessor if you know it, loop the collection, or use `Where()` to search it:

```
var email = clientList[index].ClientEmail
```

or

```
foreach (var client in clientList)
{
    var email = client.ClientEmail
}
```

or

```
var email = clientList.Where(x=>x.ClientName == <clientName>).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What does the < > mean in the Where() method?

Comment: If you mean `<clientName>` I'm using that as a placeholder for your data.

Comment: Ah okay, just making sure there wasn't some special syntax :)

Comment: No, in reality it will depend on the data type, so for a string: `clientList.Where(x=>x.ClientName == "clientName")`

Comment: Just pointing out that `FirstOfDefault` excepts a `Func` so it could be simplified to `clientList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ClientName == "clientName")`.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, very true.

Answer (score 5):

you can explore your list as below

```
 foreach (ClientEntry client in clientList)
  {
    //client.ClientName
    //client.ClientEmail
  }
```

to find a particular record you can search it as

```
clientList.Where(p=> p.ClientEmail == "email@domain.com").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

To access a specific of item in the list, you input the index / using foreach

```
string name = clientList[index].ClientName;

foreach(var client in clientList)
{
    name = client.ClientName; // access the item one by one
}
```

To check the existence of certain value of a property, use linq

```
bool isExist = clientList.Any(i => i.ClientName == "John");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx) !

Something like this, you can write unit test against the extension class easily and also it's straightforward to read.

```cs
public static class ClientEntriesExtension
{
   public static bool ExistEmail(this IEnumerable<ClientEntry> entries, string targetEmail)
   {
       return entries.Any(x=>x.ClientEmail == targetEmail);
   }
} 

bool exist = clientList.ExistEmail(targetEmail)
```